# Change button function at runtime in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

When the program starts running, I assign the CreateNew function to the btn_UpdateDelete button in the constructor function. But I want to replace it with UpdateFunc after the program starts running. When I click the Update button after the program starts running, the CreateNew function works. Is there a method to clear the functions I assigned earlier?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
from gui4 import Ui_mainWindow
import sys
from Database import Database
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_mainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.LoadData()
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.clicked.connect(self.CreateNew)
        self.ui.btn_Delete.clicked.connect(self.Delete)
        self.ui.tableWidget.clicked.connect(self.doubleClick)
        self.ui.btn_Reset.clicked.connect(self.Reset)
        self.selectedId = -1
        self.selectedRowId = -1

    def LoadData(self):
        data = Database.getInstance().BringAllTheData()
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        count = 0
        for d in data:
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(count, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d[0])))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(count, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(d[1]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(count, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d[2])))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(count, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d[3])))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(count, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d[4])))
            count = count + 1

    def CreateNew(self):
        database = Database.getInstance()
        lectureName = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        noteOne = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        noteTwo = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        noteThree = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
        if lectureName is not None and noteOne is not None and noteTwo is not None and noteThree is not None:
            database.Create(lectureName, int(noteOne), int(noteTwo), int(noteThree))
        self.Reset()
        self.LoadData()

    def clearLines(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.clear()
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.clear()

    def Reset(self):
        self.selectedId = -1
        self.selectedRowId = -1
        self.clearLines()
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.setText('Add')
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.clicked.connect(self.CreateNew)

    def doubleClick(self):
        database = Database.getInstance()
        for item in self.ui.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(item.row(), item.column(), item.text())
            if item.column() == 0:
                self.selectedId = int(item.text())
            else:
                self.selectedId = -1
            self.selectedRowId = self.ui.tableWidget.item(item.row(), 0).text()
        data = database.BringById(int(self.selectedRowId))
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(str(data[0][1]))
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setText(str(data[0][2]))
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText(str(data[0][3]))
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setText(str(data[0][4]))
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.setText('Update')
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.clicked.connect(self.UpdateFunc)
        print(self.selectedId)
        print(self.selectedRowId)

    def Delete(self):
        database = Database.getInstance()
        if self.selectedId != -1:
            print(self.selectedId)
            database.DeleteById(int(self.selectedId))
            self.LoadData()
            self.clearLines()

    def UpdateFunc(self):
        database = Database.getInstance()
        lectureName = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        noteOne = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        noteTwo = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        noteThree = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
        if lectureName is not None and noteOne is not None and noteTwo is not None and noteThree is not None:
            database.Update(self.selectedRowId, lectureName, int(noteOne), int(noteTwo), int(noteThree))
        self.clearLines()
        self.LoadData()
def create_app():
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
create_app()
```

Comment: Please correct your formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like there is the `connect` method to assign signals to slots, there is a `disconnect` method that removes previously connected slots.  So in your `CreateNew` method at the bottom you can disconnect the method from your signal and attach the UpdateFunc method as the new slot.

```
    def CreateNew(self):
        database = Database.getInstance()
        lectureName = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        noteOne = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        noteTwo = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        noteThree = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
        if lectureName is not None and noteOne is not None and noteTwo is not None and noteThree is not None:
            database.Create(lectureName, int(noteOne), int(noteTwo), int(noteThree))
        self.Reset()
        self.LoadData()
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.clicked.disconnect(self.CreateNew)
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.clicked.connect(self.UpdateFunc)
```

Alternatively, you could simply set a flag attribute on your class instance `DatabaseCreated` and set it to False, and update it upon the creation of the database.  This would avoid having to need to seperate functions that nearly identical.

For example:

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        ...
        self.ui.btn_UpdateAdd.clicked.connect(self.updateFunc)
        self.dbCreated = False
        ...

    def updateFunc(self):
        database = Database.getInstance()
        lectureName = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        noteOne = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        noteTwo = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        noteThree = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
        if lectureName is not None and noteOne is not None and noteTwo is not None and noteThree is not None:
            if not self.dbCreated:
                database.Create(lectureName, int(noteOne), int(noteTwo), int(noteThree))
                self.dbCreated = True
            else:
                database.Update(self.selectedRowId, lectureName, int(noteOne), int(noteTwo), int(noteThree))
        self.Reset()
        self.LoadData()
```

This way you can complete get rid of the `StartNew` method, and don't need to worry about disconnecting the signal.